# Should I checkout to div before creating a new branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

Is far as I know, when we create a new branch, it is based on the branch that we are before creation. Suppose that I am `branch-a` and I want to create `branch-b`. Then, if I create `branch-b` and then delete `branch-a` in a later time what will the `branch-b`? I think it will lose the base branch (`branch-a`). Is that true?

What is the difference between creating `branch-b` while being at `branch-a` and being at `development` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … if I create `branch-b` and then delete `branch-a` in a later time what will the `branch-b`? I think it will lose the base branch (`branch-a`). Is that true?

No. In Git there are no relations between branches. A branch is a name and a pointer to a commit, that's all. Git doesn't store branch'es creation/modification timestamps, parent branches, nothing like that.

So when a branch is created based on another branch Git copies the commit the "parent" branch points to to the new branch. After that any relation with the "base" branch is lost.

If you create `branch-b` and then delete `branch-a` nothing happens with the branch `branch-b`.

> What is the difference between creating `branch-b` while being at `branch-a` and being at `development` branch?

The only difference is what commit ID is copied to branch `branch-b` — the head commit from branch `branch-a` or `development`.

PS. BTW do you know you can create a branch based on any other branch, tag or commit ID? You're not obliged to checkout a branch to create a new branch from it. See [`git help branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch). `<start-point>` could be anything that points to a commit. The default is just `HEAD` i.e. the current commit. Examples:

```
git checkout development
git branch branch-b branch-a # create from the head commit of branch-a
git checkout -b branch-b branch-a # create from branch-a and checkout the new branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same many times,like created a new branch from develop branch and when facing some issue , I deleted develop branch. There is no affect of it on remote because you are deleting the branch reference from local only.
Hence you can delete the branch even if you have created other branch on the basis of that.